# Regular Expression To exclude sub-string name(job corps) Includes at least 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number and 1 symbol except "@"

Tags: asp.net, regex, qregularexpression

Regular Expression To exclude sub-string name(job corps)
Includes at least 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number and 1 symbol except "@"

I have written something like below :

```
^((?!job corps).)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%^&*]).*$
```

I tested with the above regular expression, not working for special character.

can anyone guide on this..

Comment: To exclude `job corps`, use `^(?!.*job corps)`, not `^((?!job corps).)`. What do you mean by "not working"? What is the example string? Try `^(?!.*job corps)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%^&*])[^@]*$` or `^(?!.*job corps)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%^&*])(?!.*@).*$`.

Comment: replace the final `.*` with `[^@]*` or an other character class (with only allowed characters) that excludes the `@`.

Comment: I have tried your one..not working for atleast one capital for rest of the condition it's working fine.

Comment: Your regex does not match `Lipak@123`, do you want to match it? BTW, [`Lipak@123!`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!.*job+corps)(%3f%3d.*%5b0-9%5d)(%3f%3d.*%5ba-z%5d)(%3f%3d.*%5bA-Z%5d)(%3f%3d.*%5b!%23%24%25%5e%26*%5d).*%24&i=Lipak%40123!) is matched as it has all the required symbols.

Comment: lipak&123 should not match because Upper case is missing.BTW I need to accept all the symbols except @

Comment: These strings you post in comments [do not match](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!.*job+corps)(%3f%3d.*%5b0-9%5d)(%3f%3d.*%5ba-z%5d)(%3f%3d.*%5bA-Z%5d)(%3f%3d.*%5b!%23%24%25%5e%26*%5d).*%5cr%3f%24&i=Lipak%40123!%0d%0alipak%26123%0d%0alipak%40123&o=m) with `^(?!.*job corps)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%^&*]).*$`. You must be using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev), your answer is correct

^(?!.*job corps)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%^&*])(?!.*@).*$

can verify the expression in following url:

http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your requirements, you can use this pattern:

```
^(?![^a-z]*$|[^A-Z]*$|[^0-9]*$|[^!#$%^&*]*$|.*?job corps)[^@]*$
```

If you only want to allow characters from `[a-zA-Z0-9^#$%&*]` changes the pattern to:

```
^(?![^a-z]*$|[^A-Z]*$|[^0-9]*$|[^!#$%^&*]*$|.*?job corps)[a-zA-Z0-9^#$%&*]*$
```

details:

```
^ # start of the string
(?! # not followed by any of these cases
    [^a-z]*$  # non lowercase letters until the end
  |
    [^A-Z]*$  # non uppercase letters until the end
  |
    [^0-9]*$
  |
    [^!#$%^&*]*$
  |
    .*?job corps # any characters and "job corps"
)
[^@]* # characters that are not a @
$     # end of the string
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA9yB9/1)

Note: you can write the range `#$%&` like `#-&` to win a character.

Comment: Atleast one Upper case is failing.

Comment: @Kapil: works well for me, see the demo. (You have probably added a case insensitive flag during your test)

Comment: I verified it's not working for atleast one Upper case http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: even in the demo if I haven't give any Upper case letter it's not validating...it should validate for atleast one upper case letter ..